# How to take off 2-3 variables from an int?

Tags: java, string, int

So for this program the user gives me a date, month, day, year, all in numbers. If the user gives me "1975" I just want "75", if the user gives me "2004", I want "104", etc. I need this number for a calculation that solves for the day of the week.

So what would be the best way to do this? Would I need to convert it to a string, make a smaller string, and convert that back to an int? Is there an easier way?

Comment: If the numbers are given as `int`s, then subtract 1900.

Comment: It seems like you could use `Calendar` or Joda Time for _that solves for the day of the week_.

Comment: @rgettman This can be part of an answer.

Comment: Not commenting on your date computation. To get 75 from 1975 and 104 from 2004, you can simply substract 1900 or use modulo (%) 1900 i.e. 2004 % 1900 and 1975 % 1900.

Comment: I don't want to wax hypothetical about your input string, so it'd be nice if you provided what you expect to come from the user.

Answer (score 0):

if what you want is the day of the week then use

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(yourDate);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

isn't this easier?

Answer (score 0):

simply you can find the desired number by taking num modulo 1900.